# why does NSManagedObject changedValues return all modified attributes and relationships even after saving changes in child MOC?

Tags: core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My setup is one main moc with a persistent store coordinator and an SQLite persistent store. 
I'm trying to asynchronously (and potentially concurrently) retrieve data from a server, parse it into CoreData objects and then save those new objects into the persistent store and have them available in the main moc.

So I tried 2 approaches:

1. Each time I go fetch from the server, I do so inside a GCD block (concurrent global queue with normal priority) where I create a new context with `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` which shares the presistent store coordinator with the main moc. When I'm done parsing the JSON and have the new managed objects, I save this "local" context which sends `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to the main context, which in turn does the merge.
2. Each time I go fetch from the server, I don't dispatch a GCD block but rather I create a child context with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. This context has the main context as parent but no store coordinator. Then I call `-performBlock:` on the child context, where I parse the JSON into CoreData and tell the child context to save, which in turn triggers the main context to merge.

Now, what I noticed is that approach 1 triggers what seems to be an exception but otherwise works. I say this because if I set a generic exception breakpoint to break on any Objective-C throw, it always halts when a local-to-GCD-block context saves. It's always a thread other than the main one, and even though it looks like an exception, the save error out param is nil after the save. What's more, the objects in the main context seem consistent (since I know the data they are supposed to have). And calling `-savedChanges:` on any of these objects (after the main context merged) returns no values, which is what I'd expect.

For the second approach, I don't get the exception breakpoint halting anywhere (which seems good), but... while the right data is in the right objects after the main context merge, calling `-changedValues` returns all the values (attributes and/or relationships) that were populated in the child context. This I would not expect, since in theory, I did save and the save should have been pushed up to the main context and the main context did merge.

So I'm confused.

I need `-changedValues:` to only return values if these were changed after the master context saved, since I use these values to figure out that my app has changed a mo's state and the new state needs to be pushed back to the server.

I'd really appreciate any help / pointers with either approach 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

A child context saves **into** its parent. That is, once the child has saved its changes, these changes appear in the parent, and within the parent they are flagged as *changed* because the parent still needs to change these.

I'd generally discourage use of parent-child context setups, because they have a lot of drawbacks. More info in the *Working with Multiple Contexts* chapter in [our book](https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/).